# standalone pay as you go flask/web app on azure

Tags: python, azure, flask

I own and manage a scientific computation python/c++ library and we have built a standalone flask web interface to it. Now the application (flask web ui and backend library) runs as a standalone on ones computer in a docker container. We are thinking of taking this application to a cloud provider (thinking azure) and monetize it.
We are debating still but we don't know how to do the following

- Each user must have his own container instance running for him in isolation from all other users (no shared storage between users)
- Storage must be provisioned per user (maybe 5 giga bytes) per container launch or the container can link to a user blob storage to store the computation files
- Some computation that our solution provide must run on multiple cores, the user must have to choose the number of cores his container needs at first prior to launching his service
- Calculations can last hours and maybe days sometimes where the user will be most likely interacting with the ui (library) to adjust parameters and steer the computation
- Authentication is a must because users must pay for the service

What i described is a simple problem for home computer application where users can purchase a license or online authenticate and pay per hours of usage on their own machine. 
I am not sure how that translates to the cloud. One would hope that there a PAAS or SAAS solution infrastructure for that.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

regards

Comment: There is no service by any cloud vendor that meets your requirements. You will need to spin up your own SaaS, manage authentication, billing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a prebuilt (SaaS) solution for this, then there is no official product for this in Azure. It is very doable, however, and I can give you some advice on how to accomplish it on Azure. Of course, this will vary based on the cloud provider you ultimately choose.

As John Hanley mentioned, you will need to build your own authentication and billing. Azure AD, particularly AAD B2C, may help with authentication, but you still need to implement it.

From what I can tell, there are 3 other elements to your system:

1. Persistent storage, segregated by user.
2. Compute resources, segregated by user.
3. Management portal. This would likely include the existing interface plus your configuration options, billing and authentication. Whether you simply modify the existing app to handle this specific task for multiple users or deploy one per user is up to you.

There are three main concepts that will help you with managing resources. The [management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/), the [consumption API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/consumption-api-overview), and [ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/). Assuming you want to stick with Python, [there is an SDK available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/python-sdk-azure-overview) to help you accomplish this.

The management API and ARM templates are what is going to allow you to create, configure, and remove the resources for each user. You may want to track usage yourself, but the consumption API will help you to retrieve information about what each user cost you to calculate what you will bill them.

ARM templates are a set of configuration options that you can use to define what you want to create each time you are deploying resources. You can use parameters to customize a template for a specific deployment.

Big picture, you have two options: spin up one resource and then segregate it by user or to create a completely separate set of resources for each user using [resource groups](https://www.otava.com/reference/how-to-use-azure-resource-groups-a-simple-explanation/) or tags to manage them. If you want to bill based on the consumption API, separate resources is going to be much easier to figure out what each user owes.

---

*1. Persistent storage, segregated by user.*

For storage solutions, [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction) is the service to look at. It does allow you to choose whether to use a single resource or one per user. Pricing is per GB so the difference is in management, not cost. Depending on your compute resource, you may be able to use the default storage for it, but it will depend on what else you need. For example, a small dataset could be kept on the main drive for a VM, but deleting the VM when calculations are complete also deletes that drive. Using storage separately allows you to keep that without continuing to pay for the VM.

*2. Compute resources, segregated by user*

Personally, I think your best bet here is going to be either VMs or Azure AKS/Container Services.

Using [VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/) directly are going to minimize the amount of reconfiguring required for your application at the price of speed to spin up and some flexibility. The range of VM sizes available will allow your users a lot of flexibility, and if you give user their own VM then isolation is built in.

Another option is using AKS/Container services to manage the underlying VMs. You mention the app is running in a container, but I'm not sure whether or not it could be easily adapted. Keep in mind that Container services is built on to of AKS, but you are less involved in the cluster management. This would be a more common scenario if you want to run multiple users on the same cluster (you can still isolate them) as spinning up a whole cluster for each user is probably going to create overhead you don't need.

Based on what you are describing, I think that [Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/) may be a possibility for your compute resource, but I can't tell from your question.

*3. Management portal.*

You can deploy this to the same VM/container as your compute is running on or you can use [App Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) for this aspect. I'm not sure you would need dedicated capacity per user for this, but there are plenty of options that are essentially one App Service per VM. The advantage of this over deploying to a VM is the same as most IaaS vs. PaaS conversations- you might need to adjust the web app a bit to run on App Services, but it means you don't have to worry about a lot of the low level configuration.

Comment: Appreciate your all embracing and generous answer. It's a bummer cloud service provider don't have a simple solution for such a common problem. I already thought about the VM solution but that would expose some part of our code hence IP and this is something we can't afford. We containerized the library in flask webapp and the container launches the webapp that the user will interact with. There is no need for the user to execute and browse the container os.

Comment: Is it possible to run this app in a serverless manner? A static html form will authenticate the new client with some parameters such as user's blob storage and number of cpu, ram etc. Then that serverless request will launch a the container and return the url for the user to start working. Just a thought

Comment: I can understand why you wouldn't want to expose the VM itself. Your idea of only allowing access through the web is probably the right idea to prevent exposing your code. The reason why I didn't suggest Functions (our main serverless offering) or something similar is because in order to get the rest of your requirements, you'd need to run it on a dedicated App Services plan, which drastically reduces your options for sizing.

Comment: Backing  with a VM is really what gives you that sizing flexibility you are looking for. You don't have to give the user direct access to the VM- using the web portal to hide the VM from their view is a good one. Take almost any cloud service and that's how they work behind the scenes.

Comment: how about azure lab services as a starter ? each user independently and at any time can launch a lab which will automatically startup the flask web app ...

Comment: Lab Services, and it's cousin DevTest Labs, are geared towards things like classrooms and developer VMs where the consumers login to the VMs themselves. That's something you wanted to avoid if I understand you correctly. It could work but you won't get some of the benefits of self-service ssh/rdp. Lab Services is going to be a bit more expensive than VMs by themselves, but DevTest Labs currently only bills for the underlying services. The primary difference between the two is that Lab Services handles more of the management, but also gives you fewer options.

Comment: Correct, i want to avoid exposing the code and having users login and browse the VM. Apparently i am wrong but i thought i can auto-launch the web-app upon user login like other labs i've seen that automatically launch Jupyter notebook. I was hoping i can do something like that where instead of launching jupyter it will be my webapp and have users pay for their own consumption as a market trial before investing in a more cloud standard/adequate solution.

Comment: It could work, I think it's going to come down to the ideal solution that is specific to your use case. I don't have all the details to make a determination. For that reason my goal is less "this is how to implement this" and more "here is what the services that best fit the information I have and some things to consider when deciding which ones to utilize".

Comment: I did have another employee reach out to me that I think you may be working with and I'm happy to stay plugged in to that conversation if you would like. If you want to reach me directly, you can send an email to  azcommunity (at) microsoft.com to my attn with a link to this thread.